# Реализовать регистрацию по нескольким полям кроме login и pass

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

Подскажите, как реализовать (что почитать или где посмотреть)..

Регистрация должна состоять из полей

- логин
- пароль
- почта
- Имя
- Фамилия
- телефон
- Страна
- Регион(область)
- Город

Как осуществить стандартную регистрацию по логину и паролю я знаю и все работает. Делал по [примеру](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-xml-configuration-maven-jsp-and-mysql/)

Как сделать сохранение остальных полей в БД?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте классу `User` нужные вам поля, а на сайте добавьте их в [этом месте](https://github.com/hellokoding/registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/registration.jsp#L57) по шаблону существующих.

Comment: Спасибо. Делал аналогичный пример. Вылетали ошибки!